# How to sum dynamic columns in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

Assume I have a table with 3 columns. Is there possible sum of each column without specifying name of the column?

And is there possible create a table with dynamic name of the column, and then sum of each column?

**UPDATE:** Here is my sample.
First, I do a query and get the result like this:

```
---------
|  Col  |
---------
|  DLX  |
|  SUI  |
|  PRE  |
|  TWQ  |
---------
```

The number of row maybe different each time, and then I create a table with columns from rows above like this:

```
---------------------------------
|  DLX  |  SUI  |  PRE  |  TWQ  |
---------------------------------
```

And then I fill data the table from another table. After all, I sum each column. Because I will not know exactly name of the column, so I need sum of each column without specifying name of the column.

Comment: Do you mean you want to create column names that include the sum of the individual columns? (i.e column 1 sum = 25, column 1 name = `column 25`).

Comment: If there is ONLY 3 columns it is better to write your query by hand.

Comment: please provide sample input and expected result

Comment: @TheGameiswar Please refer my new update question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your table is small (i.e. 10 columns) I would just do it manually. But if it's like 20+ columns, I would employ some dynamic sql.

To answer your question directly, yes, you can dynamically create a table with dynamic column names using dynamic sql.

Here's one way to do it: 
You can use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` View to get all the column names and put them in a temp table.

```
SELECT NAME INTO #COLUMNS 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = YourTable
```

Next, create a temp table to store your sums.

```
CREATE TABLE #SUMS (
COLUMN_NAME NVARCHAR(MAX),
SUM_COLUMN INT
)
```

You can then use dynamic sql and a loop to sum each column.

```
WHILE EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 * FROM #COLUMNS)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @COLUMN NVARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM #COLUMNS)
        DECLARE @DYNAMICSQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT ' + @COLUMN + ' AS COLUMN_NAME, SUM(' + @COLUMN + ') FROM YourTable'

        INSERT INTO #SUMS
        EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @DYNAMICSQL

        DELETE FROM #COLUMNS
        WHERE NAME = @COLUMN
    END
```

Then you would need another dynamic sql and loop to loop through the new table and create a temp table with the column names you want using the sum values and the table name you want.

You should be able to do that using the code already supplied above.

Comment: *lol* is incongruously here. SQL must be written in upper case. The part with `CREATE TABLE ` is not properly formatted. If you are rejecting my edit - please format it by yourself.

Comment: I meant it as using the word dynamic three times in the sentence and not to mock the OP. I'll remove it. And you're right. I totally forgot.

Answer (score 0):

At first I thought about pivoting but then came up with this:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (  --Table to generate input you need
    [Col] nvarchar(3)
)
DECLARE @query nvarchar(max) -- a variable that will store dynamic SQL query
DECLARE @table_name nvarchar(max) = 'Temp' --A name of table to create

INSERT INTO @Table VALUES
('DLX'),
('SUI'),
('PRE'),
('TWQ')

SELECT @query = ISNULL(@query,'CREATE '+@table_name+' TABLE (') + QUOTENAME([Col]) + ' nvarchar(max),'
FROM @Table

SELECT @query = SUBSTRING(@query,1,LEN(@query)-1) +')'

EXEC sp_executesql @query
```

That will execute a query (`PRINT @query` to see the result below):

```
CREATE Temp TABLE ([DLX] nvarchar(max),[SUI] nvarchar(max),[PRE] nvarchar(max),[TWQ] nvarchar(max))
```

Which will create a temp table for you.

Then you can insert in that table in the pretty same way.